# Why MDADM remove one of my Raid1 disk randomly?

Tags: linux, raid, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mdadm

I have a rapsberry pi 2 with 2 HDD connected to it thanks to a SATA-USB adapter. They are Raid1 mounted with MDADM. 
The problem is that one of the two disks is randomly removed and marked as "Faulty".

Here some logs, don't hesitate to ask for more :

E-mail generated by MDADM :

DegradedArray event :

```
This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm
running on jeedom

A DegradedArray event had been detected on md device /dev/md0.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0](F) sdb1[1]
      1953382464 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 1/15 pages [4KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

(Strange detail : it report "sda" and "sdb" instead of "sdc" and "sdd")

Fail event :

```
This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm
running on jeedom

A Fail event had been detected on md device /dev/md0.

It could be related to component device /dev/sdc1.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [raid1] 
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[0](F) sdd1[1]
      1953382464 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

mdadm --detail /dev/md0

```
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Jan 24 22:04:22 2017
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 1953382464 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953382464 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Wed Apr 24 07:26:28 2019
          State : active, degraded
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 1
  Spare Devices : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       0        0        0      removed
       1       8       17        1      active sync

       0       8        1        -      faulty
```

sudo mdadm --misc -E /dev/sdc

```
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
```

(same for both disks)

sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F5D21ED7-E3A8-4B23-82EC-213CC1768D42

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 3907029134 3907027087  1.8T Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdd: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CD4D815E-944C-467D-9262-248FED949EC3

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdd1   2048 3907029134 3907027087  1.8T Linux filesystem
```

cat /var/log/syslog | grep Dev

```
Apr 26 07:03:54 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 104 to 108
Apr 26 07:03:54 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 3 Spin_Up_Time changed from 97 to 98
Apr 26 07:03:54 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 71 to 72
Apr 26 07:03:54 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 29 to 28
Apr 26 07:03:54 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], open device worked again, warning condition reset after 2 emails
Apr 26 07:03:55 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 72 to 73
Apr 26 07:03:55 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 28 to 27
Apr 26 07:03:55 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.ST2000VN004_2E4164-W524Y2DZ.ata.state
Apr 26 07:03:55 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], state written to /var/lib/smartmontools/smartd.ST2000VN004_2E4164-W524YGBP.ata.state
Apr 26 07:03:55 jeedom hciattach[441]: Device setup complete
Apr 26 07:34:08 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is in STANDBY mode, suspending checks
Apr 26 07:34:13 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], is in STANDBY mode, suspending checks
Apr 26 18:03:55 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], is back in ACTIVE or IDLE mode, resuming checks (21 checks skipped)
Apr 26 18:03:55 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Prefailure Attribute: 1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate changed from 108 to 109
Apr 26 18:03:55 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 72 to 68
Apr 26 18:03:55 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sda [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 28 to 32
Apr 26 18:03:55 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], is back in ACTIVE or IDLE mode, resuming checks (21 checks skipped)
Apr 26 18:03:56 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel changed from 73 to 69
Apr 26 18:03:56 jeedom smartd[440]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 27 to 31
```

sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb -d sat

```
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [armv7l-linux-4.4.38-v7+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST2000VN004-2E4164
Serial Number:    W524YGBP
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0a81277c5
Firmware Version: SC60
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5900 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Apr 26 18:19:18 2019 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (  107) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 258) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x10bd) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   119   100   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       216926912
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   098   096   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   020    Old_age   Always       -       3937
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   068   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       6933039
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   079   079   000    Old_age   Always       -       18868
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       39
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       12885098514
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   073   073   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   067   038   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 33 (0 174 36 23 0)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       27
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3937
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   033   062   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (0 16 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     18410         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

/etc/fstab

```
    proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
    /dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
    /dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
    # a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
    #   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
    tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   defaults,size=128M                                       0 0
    /dev/md0        /media/HDD      ext4    defaults,nofail,noatime,nodiratime        0       0
    UUID=8c0ed3a6-ad04-4d8f-8932-e4c160fec0ac /backup ext4 defaults,noatime,nofail 0 0
```

/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE /dev/sdc1
#DEVICE /dev/sdd1
DEVICE partitions
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=jeedom:0 UUID=19cb497c:c70d1686:fc290ad3:d2ed202b

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
#MAILADDR root
MAILADDR xxxxxxxxx@xxx.xxx
MAILFROM HomeBox - mdadm

# definitions of existing MD arrays

# This configuration was auto-generated on Tue, 24 Jan 2017 21:47:51 +0100 by mkconf
```

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: More useful then your disk info would be the lig entry generated. Most likely your drives are not designed to work with RAID and they are timing out during reads/writes.  (Ive not used USB fir RAID but have seen this with regular SATA drives. The disks themselves were fine. Replacing the drives with "RAID capable" drives fixed it - of-course, USB could be adding another problem.

Comment: Sorry but, what is the "the lig entry generated" ? My disks are both Seagate Ironwolf 2To so I think they are ok for raid, doesn't they ?

Comment: Sorry - typo (from cellphone). I meant log entry generated.

Comment: Yes, Ironwolf drives should work in RAID.

Comment: Ok, but again, what "log entry" do you want to see ? Is there a command to run ?

Comment: I dint use a Pi so I cant advise exactly where to look fir it - most likely in /var/log (often syslog ir messages) - the exact location is distro dependant. There is no command however its a text file that can easily be read with "less" or notepad, it will contain information about the disks and RAID state at the time of failure.

Comment: I added some logs to my first post, can you tell me if it's normal ?

Comment: I cant answer authoratively, but the drive seems OK to me. I do however notice the drive going into and out of standby mode and posit that this is very likely your issue - presumably when in standby mode its taking longer to wake up and respond, and thus being marked as faulty and kicked fron the array. Also have a read of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/395566/is-mdadm-fail-a-definitive-status

Comment: Thanks. But the post you linked me ask to format the disk. Is it useful if it a standby mode issue ? Is it possible to ask mdadm to wait the disk longer ? Or maybe deactivate the standby mode ?

Comment: I added /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf and /etc/fstab in my post, any advice ?